# How to customize the height highlightings with tikzmark package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, highlighting, tikzmark

How to customize the height of highlightings with tikzmark package?.
[image]

In the documentation, page 17-18, you can see the explanation (at lower part in this message) https://ctan.javinator9889.com/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzmark/tikzmark.pdf  but can´t change the highlighting height (an offset,...)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[x11names,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzmarklibrary{highlighting}

\begin{document}

The sun was shining on the sea, shining with all its might.
\StartHighlighting[fill=cyan!50]
 And this was very odd because it was the middle of the night.
 \StopHighlighting
\StartHighlighting[fill=cyan!20]
 And this was very odd because it was the middle of the night.
\StopHighlighting

The moon was up there sulkily because she thought the sun had no
business to be there after the day was done.
\StartHighlighting[fill=magenta!50]
‘‘It’s very rude of him,’’ she said, ‘‘to come and spoil the fun.’’
\StopHighlighting

\end{document}
```

**The question is solved in the Alan Munn comment, the first one.**

[image]

Comment: The keys need to be added explicitly: `\StartHighlighting[fill=cyan!50,highlighter/initial height=2ex,highlighter/final height=2ex]` for example. Not sure if that was intended.

Comment: Except that if you do that, it applies to every other following highlights in the document. It should stay local, but it doesn't.

Comment: @AlanMunn Your solution it´s perfect. I didn´t know how to modify that values. I tried what you typed but without "highlighter/" before each parameter. Thank you.

Comment: I've raised [an issue](https://github.com/loopspace/tikzmark/issues/16) on the `tikzmark` repo, since I don't think this behaviour is how things should work. That's also why I just commented instead of making an answer.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for using this extension of the `tikzmark` library.  It is experimental, so feedback from users is very helpful in shaping how it develops further.  Alan's raised an issue on github so I can easily refer to this again.

Comment: Here's an attempt to fix these issues https://github.com/loopspace/tikzmark/commit/5edae280803ca5e4ec2a1f5fcac5108c95bf9c08 if you're willing to test, that would be much appreciated!